# Is there anything wrong with the way I'm calling this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, angular, filesaver.js

I want to call the `saveFile()` function in an Angular component, but it's not working. Have I done something wrong?

This is the html template of my Angular component:

```
<div class="Tree" onload="saveFile()">
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes">
<ng-template #treeNodeTemplate let-node let-index="index">
<a  routerLinkActive="active" ><span>{{ node.data.description }}</span></a>
  </ng-template>
</tree-root>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


<script src="FileSaver.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function saveFile(){
    var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");

}
</script>
```

Comment: Are any error messages reported on the Console in your browser's developer tools? I would expect to see something like `ReferenceError: saveAs is undefined`.

Comment: i think this is the problem : events in angular are written between parentheses => `(onload)`

Comment: No, there aren't any errors

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid I added the parentheses , but it still doesn't work

Comment: You can't have <script> in templates.

Comment: @estus Should I put the script in a separate file?

Comment: You've already got component class. All component-related code you've got should go there. It depends if FileSaver.js needs its own file.

Comment: `FileSaver.js` is a js  file that contains the `saveAs` function that I need to use.